# SCRIPT5009: "$" не определено

Tags: jquery, php

Может кто-то сталкивался? jQuery вызывает php, который в echo отдает

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert(($.fn.jquery));
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

ИЕ9

Comment: не подключена библиотека jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, как писал [@ROOT](/users/4208/root), действительно не подключена jQuery, но возможны чудеса с $, который используется и в php, так что подробности не повредят

Comment: Вот нашлось еще: http://govnokod.ru/12057
Возможно, собака зарыта там